# Expand dataframe behaving strangely in R

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I have the following dataframe in R

```
DF2<-data.frame("A"= c(1,2,3,4,5), "B"= c(1,2,3,4,5), "C"= c(1,2,3,5,10), 
"D"=c(2,3,10,NA, NA))
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
```

The dataframe appears as follows

```
   A B  C  D
 1 1 1  1  2
 2 2 2  2  3
 3 3 3  3 10
 4 4 4  5 NA
 5 5 5 10 NA
```

I have used the following code to expand the dataset using mutate as follows

```
 D3<-DF2 %>%
 mutate(E= pmax(A, B,C, D, na.rm = T)) %>%
 complete(E = seq(max(E)))
```

I have obtained the following output

```
      E     A     B     C     D

  1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
  2     2     1     1     1     2
  3     3     2     2     2     3
  4     4    NA    NA    NA    NA
  5     5     4     4     5    NA
  6     6    NA    NA    NA    NA
  7     7    NA    NA    NA    NA
  8     8    NA    NA    NA    NA
  9     9    NA    NA    NA    NA
 10    10     3     3     3    10
 11    10     5     5    10    NA
```

As can be seen, I have obtained 2 rows in column E with value= 10. The expected output is as follows

```
     E  A  B  C  D
 1   1  1  1  1 NA
 2   2  2  2  2  2
 3   3  3  3  3  3
 4   4  4  4 NA NA
 5   5  5  5  5 NA
 6   6 NA NA NA NA
 7   7 NA NA NA NA
 8   8 NA NA NA NA
 9   9 NA NA NA NA
10  10 NA NA NA 10
```

I have also attempted using these codes

```
 DF2%>%mutate(E=pmax(A,B,C,D,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 complete(E=full_seq(E,1))
```

This yielded the following

```
      E      A     B     C     D

1     2      1     1     1     2
2     3      2     2     2     3
3     4     NA     NA    NA    NA
4     5      4     4     5     NA
5     6     NA    NA     NA    NA
6     7     NA    NA     NA    NA
7      8    NA    NA     NA    NA
8      9    NA    NA     NA    NA
9     10     3     3     3     10
10    10     5     5     10    NA
```

I request someone to help me here.

Comment: You have two rows with value `E = 10` in `DF2 %>%
    mutate(E= pmax(A, B,C, D, na.rm = T))` ? which one do you expect to get selected in the final output and why?

Comment: I have given an expected output Sir. Thats the output I expect. Its in the question. To be clear,  E should take the range of values of all 4 columns A, B, C< D separated by 1 as a sequence. Next The new dataframe column A should align such that where The value of A, B, C, D should equal the value in E. Else the space should be NA

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `m<-max(DF2,na.rm=TRUE)` followed by`as.data.frame(lapply(DF2,function(x) NA^(!seq_len(m) %in% x)*seq_len(m)))`.

Comment: This works sir. Thank you. Is there a DPLYR based solution to the same